# How to use Base64.decode for an array of string in Java 8

Tags: java, base64, decode

How to use `Base64.decode` for an array of string in Java 8? how `getStrings` work? This part of the code is working in Java 6 but I got the following error in Java 8, could you please guide me on this problem.

```
public byte[] getBytes(String key, byte defaults[])
{
    String lines[] = getStrings(key);
    if (lines == null)
        return defaults;

    return Base64.decode(lines);
}
```

The error is

```
error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         return Base64.decode(lines);
[javac]                      ^
[javac]   symbol:   method decode(String[])
[javac]   location: class Base64
```

follow this instruction of base64 decode for Java 8 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html), it shows that there is no command decode(string[]) but, I can't find the replace function for this.

Comment: You are trying to pass array of `String`.

Comment: convert string[] to string

Comment: @user3644708 Thank you so much, combining with the answer below make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The class Base64 doesn't contain that method**

Change this `Base64.decode(lines);` by this `Base64.getDecoder().decode(lines);`

**Take a look at the apidoc here:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getDecoder

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes it work but still have convert string[] to string before use the above method